# Google chrome (newer versions), navigage back and forward shortcut (mac)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

In newer versions the back button stopped working as expected. What is the new shortcut for going back. Specially in Mac

Comment: Edit your question and indicate what version of Chrome you are using.

Answer (score 19):

its `Command + Left-Arrow`

Also, check out

https://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/google-chrome-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: Your answer is correct, but the link is not helpful for macs. It says "Press Backspace, or Alt and the left arrow together." and `Alt + Left Arrow` doesn't do anything on OSX.

Comment: Agreed that this is correct, but does not work if inside a form, or content like a PDF is loaded in the active window.

Comment: Is this still accurate in 2020? I'm on macOS 10.15.3 and Google Chrome 80.0.3987.85 and I think that this shortcut has change very recently. It now shows `⌘ + [` in the history menu.

Comment: It's a travesty how hard it is to find simple information like this in public docs

Comment: @Liam what is history menu? ⌘ + [ - windows key plus square bracket - does not work either. I am on Mac mini 2020 current os and Chromium. Moreover, my arrow down and up do not work as in other browsers. I get a cursor, in other browsers I can scroll the page with arrow keys.

Comment: [the answer further down](https://superuser.com/a/1811323/411849) helps.

Comment: @Timo [This History menu](https://imgur.com/PmgiHph)

Answer (score 13):

As of 2020:

- Back: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
- Forward: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: which is a pretty shitty combination ergonomics-wise if you happen to be on a Scandic keyboard .... like Left Command + right option + 8 or 9 ...

Answer (score 4):

Google has a support page listing out all of the shortcut keys for Windows and Mac OS

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

**As of 2023**, the current working shortcuts are still:

Back: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Left Arrow and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Forward: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Right Arrow and <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

The primary shortcut (i.e. the one listed in History >> Back) is the one with the <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>.

If for some reason <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Left/Right Arrow stops working and you see text cursors in places you wouldn't normally expect, you've probably enabled Navigate Text with a cursor:

[image]

You can disable this setting by going to `chrome://settings` >> `Accessibility` or hitting <kbd>F7</kbd>, and then your <kbd>⌘</kbd> + Left/Right will be back to working again.

For a list of all Mac shortcuts Google's [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctab-window-shortcuts).

[The description of the Accessibility setting and text cursor](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/10129654?hl=en)

Comment: That explains the weirdness I was seeing and provides 2 solutions. Very nice, thank you!